# Interlock diagram troubles

Tags: control, diagram

The drawing seems to present an electric interlock system. But how the NO and NC relays being energized?
The diagonal with a box should represent fuse, but the drawing doesn't seem so?
BCT should be bushing current transformer but why it is being used here?
Didn't find anything with BCO anywhere!
Having difficulty in linking up all the things in the drawing.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would guess from context that BCO1-3 are the contactor operating coils, and that the fuse symbols are indeed fuses.

No idea what a cilactor is, Selector switch possibly?

Sometimes with old drawings you really need to go and actually look at the physical plant to be sure....